# why are the results returned by Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint and Jena different?

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, dbpedia, virtuoso

I have queried DBPedia via Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint and Jena, but the results are different. My query is :

```sql
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT (?v)) AS ?num)
FROM <http://dbpedia.org>
WHERE {
  ?x  <http://dbpedia.org/property/deathPlace>  ?v .
  ?v  rdf:type                                  ?t .
  FILTER STRSTARTS( STR(?t), STR("http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place") )
}
```

I execute my query in Jena by this function :

```java
    public static ArrayList<String> query(String queryStr) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    queryStr = SPARQL_PREFIX + queryStr;
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStr);

    // Remote execution.
    try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query)) {
        // Set the DBpedia specific timeout.
        ((QueryEngineHTTP) qexec).addParam("timeout", "10000");

        // Execute.
        ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect();
        while (rs.hasNext()) {
            result.add(rs.next().toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("============================================");
        System.err.println(queryStr);
        System.err.println("============================================");
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've set the graph to search in the `FROM` expression but the result are still different. When I execute the query on Virtuoso's SPARQL endpoint, the result is 21482, but the result returned by Jena is 9586.

Is there any idea?

Comment: I don't see any different results in the question.  What results are you actually seeing?

Comment: How are you executing the Jena query? Using "FROM" may not do what you expect it do here.

Comment: I added the details.

Comment: And how are you running it in Virtuoso?  Using code?  Or the DBpedia web interface endpoint?

Comment: I'm using the web interface and run exactly same query

Comment: If you don't get any errors when running your Jena code, then that is all the server is returning.

Comment: Is there any reason for using a string match instead of using directly the class URI?

Comment: I didn't find out where exactly you mean to use URI but if you mean when i'm getting the result;no there is no special reason for that but I don't think it causes the problem

Comment: @amirveyseh It might cause the problem if it's more expensive.  It could be that DBpedia imposes different limits on remote queries vs. queries launched from its website.  It could be that remote queries get less time, so you get fewer results in the alloted time, and so the result count is smaller.

Comment: @taylor thanks. so I think there is no way to change those settings. Maybe pagination of result can help.

Comment: I meant to use the class URI http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place directly as resource instead of variable ?t and a string comparison on it, which is more expensive.

Comment: @AKSW oh sorry I didn't understand at first. It solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: So, you can provide an answer for your own question if you want. This might help other users in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AKSW and Taylor mentioned in the comments, DBPedia has different limits on remote queries than on queries launched from its website.  In this case, string matching (which is an expensive operation) makes the query more time consuming, and the result returned by jena is only part of the actual result of the query.

To solve this we can directly use URI instead of its string :

```sql
SELECT  (COUNT(DISTINCT (?v)) AS ?num)
  FROM  <http://dbpedia.org>
 WHERE 
   {
     ?x  <http://dbpedia.org/property/deathPlace>  ?v   .
     ?v  rdf:type  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place>  .
   }
```